# How to do add more of checkbox drop-down in angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, angularjs

**Below is my code,**

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect options="master_days_name" selected-model="selected_days_name" ></div>

<select name="end_time" ng-model="PostJobData.facility_hours.end_time" data-bvalidator="required" class="form-control"  data-bvalidator-msg="Required">
    <option value="">End Time</option>
    <option ng-repeat = "val in time_array"  value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>                
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="" ng-click="addMoreFacilityHours()">  Add More</a>
```

**Current Result**

[image]

Now I want, if user click to add more then this dropdown get repeated, with tuesday, wednesday, saturday, sunday(with uncheck values)
Add more functionality

```
<div class="row dobBlock" ng-repeat="(hours_key,hours_value) in PostJobData.facility_hours">
        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect options="master_days_name" selected-model="selected_days_name" ></div>
</div>
```

Js code

```
$scope.PostJobData.facility_hours = [];

$scope.addMoreFacilityHours = function()
{
    var temp = {'days':[],'start_time':'', 'end_time':'' };
    $scope.PostJobData.facility_hours.push(temp);
    console.log($scope.PostJobData.facility_hours);
}
```

**But this giving same array clone means I want to show only uncheck option in second select box how can do this ?**

**Result**

[image]

Comment: could you provide a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: that I will create in some time

Comment: you never created the fiddle :(